# How to specify primary Image button on "Enter" in Masterpage Header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onclick, master-pages

My website is  [pbradleyonline.com](http://www.pbradleyonline.com) if you would like to actually see what is happening. I have a master page file that contains two different Image Buttons. They both serve a purpose. One redirects the user to one page if clicked and the other button is supposed to be linked to the search text box that is beside it. Once the "Search" button is clicked it should take them to another page with the results.

The problem is that, when the Textbox (also in the header) has focus, if the enter key is pressed, it is triggering the wrong button in the header and redirecting to the wrong page. I also understand that this may have something to do with the controls being Image Buttons and not standard Submit Buttons but I would like to keep them as Image Buttons.

I have tried multiple solutions including setting the "DefaultButton" property for the textbox as well as for the Panel control that both the textbox and the correct button are in. This hasn't worked. Here is the MasterPage Code.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/Pictures/PBradleyFavicon.ico" />

<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css" runat="server">
.textBox
{
 text-align: right;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 float:Right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server" >
  <div class="header"  dir="ltr">
        <div class="title">
        </div> 
        <div class="Logo" >
        <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" usesubmitbehavior="false" runat="server" Height="64px" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Pictures/PBradleyJCBLogo.jpg" 
                            style="margin-left: 0px" Width="321px" CausesValidation="False" 
                            TabIndex="3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="hideSkiplink" DefaultButton="ImageButton1">

        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
            IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/" Text="Home" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Used_Equipment.aspx" Text="Equipment">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/New_Equipment.aspx" Text="New Equipment"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Used_Equipment.aspx" Text="Used Equipment"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/jcb.aspx" Text="JCB Skid Steers"></asp:MenuItem>

                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx" Text="Online Parts" >
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx" Text="Sprayer Parts" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Farm_Equipment_Teeth.aspx" Text="Ag Teeth" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="https://www.allpartsstore.com/index.htm?customernumber=VA2352" Text="Aftermarket Tractor Parts" />
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Plastic_Supplies.aspx" Text="Plastic Supplies" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Video.aspx" Text="Customer Corner">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Forms.aspx" Text="Customer Forms"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Video.aspx" Text="Video Lounge"></asp:MenuItem>

                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Contact Us" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="ImageButton1">         
           <asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="ImageButton1_Click" ID="ImageButton1"  
                runat="server" CssClass="textBox" Height="22px" 
            ImageUrl="~/Pictures/SearchIcon2.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                Width="22px" TabIndex="1" />   
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  runat="server" DefaultButton="ImageButton1" CssClass="textBox" 
            style="margin-top: 11px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

            </asp:Panel>



    </div>

<div class="page">

    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>

<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="true" ScriptMode="Release">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
</form>
```

The controls to look at are `TextBox1` `ImageButton1` and `ImageButton2`, `ImageButton1` Should be the only button triggered when enter is pressed, at least while textbox has focus.

Here is the code for ImageButton1_Click

```
 Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click


    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Sprayer_Parts_CatalogConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString)
    Dim sql As New SqlDataSource
    Dim sql3 As New SqlCommand
    Dim sql4 As New SqlCommand
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim str As String
    sql4.Connection = Conn
    sql3.Connection = Conn
    Conn.Open()

    sql3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", TextBox1.Text)
    sql4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", TextBox1.Text)
    sql3.CommandText = "Select Category From SubCategory WHERE Category Like '%' + @Search + '%'"
    sql4.CommandText = "Select Type From SubCategory WHERE Type LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR Category LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR Order# LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'"
    If Not sql4.ExecuteReader().HasRows Then
        Response.Redirect("~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx?Search=" + "1")

    End If


    Response.Redirect("~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx?Search=" + TextBox1.Text)
    Conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Everything works fine if the button is actually clicked.

ImageButton2_Click

```
Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
    Response.Redirect("~/jcb.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: where is onClick for ImageButton2?

Comment: Sorry, Just Added it

Comment: I think in any individual form, the first button defined is always the default one used when return is pressed. I would bet that if you swapped them around for testing it works as you expect. I know this doesn't solve the issue, but I expect this is the cause.

Comment: Yes I had thought the same thing and tested it and this does solve part of the problem. I was just having trouble getting the layout back to the way it was with the buttons switched. I will keep working on this. Do you know of any other work around other than switching which button is defined first?

Comment: where is onClick in your aspx page imagebutton2?is it a typo?

Comment: I had removed it before I posted the question while I was trying to debug and figure out what was wrong And forgot to put it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the JCB button is doing is linking to another page, I guess ideally you would make it a straight forward image with a link around it so that the search button is the first/ only button.

This may not be the best way to do this any more, but in a similar previous situation I have intercepted the return keypress. For example, add this script to your page:

```
<script>
    function detectSearchBoxReturn(e) {
        var code;
        if (!e) { var e = window.event; }
        if (e.keyCode) { code = e.keyCode; }
        else if (e.which) { code = e.which; }

        if (code == 13) {
            // find your button and perform a click event.
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then on your textbox, add

```
onkeypress = "detectSearchBoxReturn(event);"
```

Obviously this doesn't work if script is disabled, and as previously stated, this may not be the best way to do it.

Comment: I am just keeping it simple for now and changing the control from ImageButton to Image and putting a link around it. This will work for me at the moment. Not really sure why I didn't think to do this in the first place I guess I just got caught up with the keypress triggering the wrong button, Thanks for your help